# MySQL ALTER TABLE to Add column auto_incremented to a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, alter-table, composite-primary-key

I've a table like

```
-------------------------------
| PK1  | PK2  | Col1  | Col2  |
-------------------------------
```

I want to ALTER TABLE so the result looks something like

```
---------------------------------------------------
| PK1 | PK2 | Col1 | Col2 | PK3 (AUTO_INCREMMENT) |
---------------------------------------------------
```

So the result of inserting would be something like

```
------------------------------------------------
| PK1 | PK2 | Col1 | Col2 | PK3(AUTOINCREMMENT)|
------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  1  | null | null |         1         |
|  1  |  1  | null | null |         2         |
|  1  |  1  | null | null |         3         |
|  1  |  2  | null | null |         1         |
|  1  |  2  | null | null |         2         |
|  1  |  2  | null | null |         3         |
|  2  |  1  | null | null |         1         |
|  2  |  1  | null | null |         2         |
|  2  |  1  | null | null |         3         |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD COLUMN `PK3` NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PK1`,`PK2`,`PK3`);
```

But I cannot DROP PRIMARY KEY if PK3 has AUTO_INCREMENT
I also tried to add the AUTO_INCREMENT later (adding PK3 normally, then create composite primary key and then

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `PK3` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

With a result of *#1075  there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An auto_increment column will increment by a fixed incremental value what you appear to want is a kind of row_number based on the values of pk1 and pk2 and it's lack of uniqueness means it cannot be a primary or unique key. In order to generate this 'row_number' you are going to have to write some custom code possibly in a trigger.

Comment: But If I dont set it as PK, then I cant have more than one value for the same (PK1,PK2).